# Type mismatch; found : Int(1) required: B

Tags: scala, generics, type-mismatch, enrich-my-library

I'm trying to extend the `List` class to give it some more streamlined way to compare the sizes, however I run into the error in the title...

Here's my code:

```
implicit class RichList[A, B](input: List[A]) {
  def >(that: List[B]): Boolean = input.size > that.size
  def <(that: List[B]): Boolean = input.size < that.size
}
```

The idea was that since all it does it compare the sizes of the lists, their types could be different and it wouldn't matter, however when I try to do this:

```
val test = List(1,2,3,4) < List(1,2,3,4,5)
```

I get the beforementioned error. If I remove B and set `that` to be of type `List[A]` it works fine, but then I wouldn't be able to use lists containing 2 different types...

Why is it that both A and B can't be the same type? Or am I missing something?

**Edit:** Ok I've found a solution to the error, which is rather simple:

```
implicit class RichList[A](input: List[A]) {
  def >[B](that: List[B]): Boolean = input.size > that.size
  def <[B](that: List[B]): Boolean = input.size < that.size
}
```

However my question still stands; why can't I do it the other way?

Comment: You can also use this: `def >(that: List[_]): ....` as you don't care about the actual type

Comment: that might actually be a good idea... odd how I never thought of that

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your helper class you define the type `B` in the class initialization. But that type is unknown until the method `>` or `<` usage.

My solution would be this.

```
implicit class RichList[A](input: List[A]) {
  def >[B](that: List[B]): Boolean = input.size > that.size
  def <[B](that: List[B]): Boolean = input.size < that.size
}
```

#### Edit

Since you asked, why its not possible in other way, consider following example.

```
List(1,2,3) > List("1", "2")
```

We hope this will implicitly expand to (*This wont happen*)

```
new RichList[Int, B](List[Int](1,2,3)).>(List[String]("1", "2"))
```

But, type `B` is not resolved to `String`. Therefore, compiler neglects this implicit conversion, and gives a compilation error.

Comment: funny, we both added the same solution at the same time